# OCR recognize Digital Digit

Tags: android, ocr, digits, firebase-mlkit

I am working on an application where I want to read digital digits from image,
for that, I use below libs,

> **anyline** is working fine to recognize but it's paid not affordable for
>   client  https://anyline.com/
>
> **ml-kit**  recognized text but not able to recognize the digital digit 
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text
>
> **Ocr** found seven segment OCR in python but how to use it in android. 
>   https://github.com/jiweibo/SSOCR

[image: capture image Digital Digit]

Can anyone have an idea about to recognize digital digits?

Comment: Related (check bottom of page): https://github.com/whitelok/image-text-localization-recognition